# What is faster? Many classes in CSS with one attribute, or write one css attribute to several html elements

Tags: html, css

what is fastest? Many classes in CSS with one attribute, or write one css attribute to several html elements. Thanks

1.example

```
.leftItem, .shopCont h1, .inAll, .stripCart, .titleItem, .middleItem, .itemIn, .quantityCart p, .strip, .cartProduct, .descript, .listFooter, .listFooterBox, .recordSelector, .listPagination, .topContent, .sideMenu, .menuHome, .menuCat1, .menuCat2, .menuCat3, .menuCat4, .menuCat5, .menuCat6, .searchHead img, .loginUser, .searchHead input, .loginTopLog img, .loginPoint, .loginLabel, .middleHeadLine, .leftTextIntro, .leftText, .actualOrder, .leftText img, .actualPrice, .minorOrder, .minorOrderPrice, .allPrice, .rightContent, .middleHeaderText, .middleHeaderText div, .middleHeaderText .middleHeadLine, .advSearch img, .advSearch span, .advSearchShow input, .advSearchShow label, .codeProd, .catSearch, .stockSearch {
float: left;
}
```

2.example

```
<div class="itemDetail menuCat1 menuCat2 menuCat3 menuCat4 menuCat5 menuCat6 searchHead img loginUser searchHead"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "faster"?
- The parsing time for the browser?
- The time it will take your HTML file to load?
- There are some other question possible...

Comment: A single class with single attribute will be better and include this class wherever u want. like .fl { float: left;}

Comment: @Ronen the time to load HTML with CSS together

Comment: @SushilKandola ok many TNX, but what I know bootstrap usually use the first example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In you case, the best option is to create a single css class (let's say `.float`), and give it to all of the relevant elements. and keep your css as clean as:

```
.float {
    float:left;
}
```

An HTML element shouldn't have so many css classes. A css Class is supposed to group together a set of styling rules, that make sense when they are together, or describe what they meant to describe.
here's an example of a good use:

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment-container">
    <h5 class="user-name">Johnny</h5>
    <p class="comment-body">Lorem ipsum.......</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.comment-container {
    color:#444;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px blue;
}
.user-name {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.comment-body {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Try to group your css rules in a way that will make them as reusable as possible, it will also make your html & css much easier to maintain.

Comment: I understand tnx 4 reply.. I'll try this method:)